# How to make VLC (or gerbera) stop renaming video files to file.mkv (or .mp4)

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have vlc 3.3.4 installed on a Sony Bravia TV XBR-55X900F (the About says Version 9). I have gerbera 1.1.0 (from gerbera -version) installed on a media server that is accessed by that TV.

If I make vlc play a file, then afterward vlc's menu shows that file has been renamed to `file.mkv` or `file.mp4` depending on the file. I can play `file.mkv` and I can make vlc show me the URL backing that file but the URL doesn't indicate the file from which it came. The URL looks like this:

```
http://ADDR/content/media/object_id/ID/res_id/0.ext/file.mkv
```

I suspect that I can find the gerbera database somewhere and find the name for the ID in the URL but I don't believe I should have to do that.

Renaming a file would not be so big a problem when a folder contains one file because I can guess the filename from its folder. But when the folder contains many played files, it's next to impossible to figure out what any of the `file.mkv` files mean. And who would want to create a folder that is destined to contain only one file just to solve such a problem?

To see if I might be able to fix the problem, I downloaded both the gerbera and vlc source looking for the string `file.mkv`. The only occurrence I found was in the following vlc search:

```
$ grep -R -i file\\.mkv .
./test/libvlc/media.c:    { "file.mkv", libvlc_media_type_file },
```

I don't believe this is relevant to my problem because it appears to be a file related to testing the vlc, not running it.

If I navigate the TV's settings (Settings->Apps->VLC) to the VLC app's settings, I can see two menu options: `Clear data` and `Clear cache`.

If I click `Clear cache` then I don't see any change in behavior in vlc. But if I click `Clear data`, then I don't see `file.mkv` but I also lose some things I don't want to lose (e.g., its favorite app status).

On the media server, I looked at /etc/gerbera/config.xml and noticed the transcoding element's enabled attribute is set to "no".

Because I can make vlc clear its data and the problem goes away, I suspect my next step should be to go to github and submit an issue for vlc but because it might be related to gerbera I wanted to ask here first. That's especially true because I doubt it would be easy for me to create a new build of vlc for my TV. I'm hoping there's something easy I can do to the gerbera configuration.

The TV's About says more:

```
Version 9
Android security patch level March 5, 2021
Kernel version 4.9.125
Build BRAVIA_ATV3_4K_UC-user 9 PTT1.190515.001.S43 671651 release-keys
```

If I play one of the affected files on my MacBook Pro using its native VLC app, the relevant (my opinion) Codec Details within the Media Information dialog shows this:

```
Stream 0
    Codec A52       Audio
    Channels        Stereo
    Sample rate     48000 Hz
    Bits per sample 32
Stream 1
    Codec             MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265)
    Video Resolution  720x480
    Buffer dimensions same as resolution
    Frame rate        29.969696
```

[Here](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/articles/S1F0793) is the link to what I think is a listing of supported file formats. Some years ago I found a link to a more complete list. I can no longer see that list.

Comment: VLC is (mostly) a player. It doesn't change the name of files. You're looking at it the wrong way. It's likely your media server software that is set to transcode the video it serves. VLC or any other local or remote player merely READS what's being served.

Comment: "On the media server, I looked at /etc/gerbera/config.xml and noticed the transcoding element's enabled attribute is set to "no"." No offense intended, but I think you missed that part of my OP. And if the problem goes away after making VLC clear its data, then that doesn't exactly lay blame on gerbera, now, does it.

Comment: There may be other settings, I'm not familiar with gerbera. One thing is for sure: NOT happening in the player. Perhaps a good idea to carefully read the documentation already available > https://docs.gerbera.io/en/stable/transcoding.html  and possibly related > https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146007/gerbera-to-transcode-avi-videos-to-h264-mkv . In a nutshell, transcoding in this context is what often users want for obvious reasons. It's unclear *why* this a problem for you.